# can I find the limit in this way?

Tags: analysis

I have to check if the sequence $b_{n}=\frac{n+cos(n^2)}{n+sin(n)}$ converges.I thought that I could find it like that:
$$-1 \leq sin(n) \leq 1 \Rightarrow n-1 \leq n+sin(n) \leq 1+n \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1+n} \leq \frac{1}{n+sin(n)} \leq \frac{1}{n-1} \Rightarrow \frac{n+cos(n^2)}{1+n} \leq \frac{n+cos(n^2)}{n+sin(n)} \leq \frac{n+cos(n^2)}{n-1} $$
Can I use this relation to find the limit of the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extend your inequalities to this:

$$ 1-\frac{2}{n+1}=\frac{n-1}{1+n}\leq\frac{n+cos(n^2)}{1+n} \leq \frac{n+cos(n^2)}{n+sin(n)} \leq \frac{n+cos(n^2)}{n-1} \leq\frac{n+1}{n-1}=1+\frac{2}{n-1}$$

and now use the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: I understand....thanks a lot....!!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Divide numerator and denominator by $n$ and notice that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cos(n^2)}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n}=0$$

Comment: So,can't I find it,using the realtion I found??

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use the following "trick"

$b_n=\dfrac{n(1+\frac{\cos n^2}{n})}{n(1+ \frac{\sin n}{n})}$. Now can you show that $b_n$ converges?

Comment: So,can't I find it,using the realtion I found??

Comment: @evinda: It looks like you are trying to use the squeeze theorem to get your limit. It shall work, but you have to do a trick like this anyway.

Comment: Could you help me find the limit,using the relation,because I got stuck right now..

Comment: @evinda: Divide numerator and denom by $n$ in your relation. Then take limits. Both limits are equal to 1. So squeeze thm gives the answer 1.